# PythonQt and Anaconda Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, qt, pythonqt

I am trying to build PythonQt against anaconda python (2.7.x).  Running the included PyGuiExample I am unable to get any Python other than the system install.

Running OS X 10.10, Qt 5.5, latest Anaconda.

I have set the python.prf as

```
PYTHON_CONFIG_PATH = /Users/me/anaconda/bin/python-config
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += $$system($${PYTHON_CONFIG_PATH} --includes)
LIBS += $$system($${PYTHON_CONFIG_PATH} --libs)
```

Two environment variables have been set

```
PYTHON_PATH /Users/me/anaconda/include/python2.7
PYTHON_LIB /Users/me/anaconda/lib
```

The build (in QtCreator) is successful with a high number of warnings about unused parameters.

Any thoughts on getting PythonQt built against a Python installation other than the system framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `python.prf` file you have the `macx` portion. You probably changed the `unix` part which is not take into account.

You should just change the lines:

```
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/Frameworks/Python.framework/Headers
LIBS += -F/usr/local/Frameworks -framework Python
```

This is what I did to use the `brew` version of python and it worked pretty well.

as result I get all the libraries in the `lib` folder and here is the linked python lib (`otool -L libPythonQt.dylib`):

```
libPythonQt.dylib:
    libPythonQt.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /usr/local/opt/python/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python (compatibility version 2.7.0, current version 2.7.0)
    /usr/local/opt/qt5/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtWidgets (compatibility version 5.5.0, current version 5.5.1)
    /usr/local/opt/qt5/lib/QtGui.framework/Versions/5/QtGui (compatibility version 5.5.0, current version 5.5.1)
    /usr/local/opt/qt5/lib/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/QtCore (compatibility version 5.5.0, current version 5.5.1)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/DiskArbitration.framework/Versions/A/DiskArbitration (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 275.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/OpenGL (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/AGL.framework/Versions/A/AGL (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /usr/local/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/5/libstdc++.6.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 7.21.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1226.10.1)
    /usr/local/lib/gcc/5/libgcc_s.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
```